# Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile is not changing

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to upload an app to Itunes Connect. I uploaded once, but received an email with errors pointing to incorrect Team ID/Identifier. So what I did is changed the Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile in the Build Settings of my app, see image below:

[image]

After that, I clicked Clean and Build. Then I created an Archive and selected an account to use in uploading the app. But in the summary page, it's showing a different Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile, see image below:
[image]

I am new in XCode/iOS development.BTW, I am using XCode 7.2

Comment: I see that your Provisioning profile is developer profile. Click on provision profile and you will see two modes Debug and Release. In debug mode it should be your - DEV profile and in your release mode you need to have Distribution Profile (again your, for Ad Hoc or App store). After that go to Schemes (it is after Run and Stop button in Xcode, it has your app name and icon). You need to create one for release mode, just create copy and in edit theBuild configuration of the Archive to Release and archive your project with that scheme.

Comment: I don't get this part: and in edit theBuild configuration of the Archive to Release and archive your project with that scheme

Comment: It is already in Release but the same problem still